# Bare, old wood spots on cedar hedge

Tags: hedge

I have recently purchased a home with a lovely cedar hedge that makes the yard quite private. In some areas, the old hedge has bare spots that seem to be called "old wood" showing through. From my research, these areas never seem to regrown or fill in. 
What should I do? Leave it? Cut the "old wood" out? Will the whole hedge eventually turn like this?

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: Hi mike! This question may be put on hold or closed because, without more information, especially pictures, we can't see what's happening to your hedge. This is explained on [this page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the [help]. You still have time to prevent that, I just wanted to let you know what's happening!

Answer (score 0):

With enough light and fertilizer they should backbud on the old wood.  I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cut that old wood be the best option and redesign with your own ideas and plants or shrubs you like.